# Un équivalent à « to suffer fools gladly » ?

Tags: anglais, expressions

L'expression anglaise « *to suffer fools gladly* » est le plus souvent utilisée sous sa forme négative (*he doesn't suffer fools gladly*) et signifie dans ce cas que la personne se fâche facilement avec les imbéciles.

Est-ce qu'il y a une expression équivalente en français ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il y a bien une phrase que j'entends parfois qui correspondrait à l'idée :

> Je ne supporte pas la bêtise humaine.

ou bien :

> J'ai du mal à supporter la bêtise humaine.

Il y a bien assez de bêtise chez les francophones pour trouver une expression qui convient. :D

Comment: Merci pour les réponses. J'accepte la votre car l’idée d'avoir du mal à supporter les imbéciles ressemble bien à la "souffrance" qui va avec.

Answer (score 7):

À ma connaissance, il n'y a pas d'expression idiomatique (peut-être que le cas se présente moins souvent en pays francophones! ;), mais ça peut se traduire comme ça :

> Il/elle montre/a peu de patience pour la bêtise.

Comment: Je n'utiliserais pas *présente* ici. Peut-être un régionalisme ?

Comment: C'est vrai, il y a des exemples, mais peu: http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=%22il+presente+peu+de%22

Comment: Et surtout ces exemples ont des sens différents.

Answer (score 3):

On peut utiliser le verbe *[souffrir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/souffrir)* (dans le sens de *tolérer*) directement pour une traduction assez proche de l'original:

> Je ne peux pas souffrir les imbéciles.

Ce n'est peut-être pas utilisé couramment, mais c'est parfaitement correct. On le trouve d'ailleurs dans une [traduction](http://www.biblestudytools.com/ost/2-corinthiens/passage.aspx?q=2-corinthiens+11:19-29) de la bible (2 Corinthiens, 11:19):

> Car, vous qui êtes sages, vous souffrez volontiers les imprudents.

D'[autres traductions](http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/suffer+fools+gladly.html) semblent cependant préférer *supporter*.